# How to make responsive side by side form elements

Tags: html, css, user-interface, responsive-design

How do you do it so that the `select` tag and `text` input will be side by side regardless of the `div`'s width, while also making `text` input responsive (occupy 100% of the width of the container `div`)

CSS:

`input[type="text"] { width: 100%; }`

HTML:

```
<div style="width:500px; background:red; padding:10px;">
   <input type="text" name="test" style="float:left;"> 
   <select style="float:left;"><option>test</option></select>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/F6Jtj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to align both on the same line with a width of `100%` than you can do it this way

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/27C9f/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <select>
        <option>Hello</option>       
        <option>World</option>
    </select>
    <span><input type="text" /></span>
</div>

.wrap span {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap input[type=text] {
    width: 100%
}
.wrap select {
    float: right
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it really necessary for the `select` tag to be placed first before `input text`?